# Listen to only two connections on websocketpp

Tags: tcp, websocket, websocket++

I had setup a simple broadcast server, using the websocketpp library, that I use for a personal HTML + Javascript chat. Everything is perfect until now, with only one exception. This chat is intended for only two people at the same time. If a third tries to come in, he or she must get a closed door. So, the logic is:

> 1 -> Server is listening.
>
> 2 -> Alice connects.
>
> 3 -> Bob connects.
>
> 4 -> Server stops listening. Broadcasting to Alice + Bob.
>
> 5 -> Carlos tries to connect, but gets a port closed.
>
> 6 -> Bob disconnects.
>
> 7 -> Carlos connects.
>
> 8 -> Server stops listening. Broadcasting to Alice + Carlos.

At first I thought this would be something simple, but after many errors and reading I am simply stuck. I can get my server to stop listening after the handshaking process, but after this the `message_handler` on server-side stops working and I can get no message from the client, even though the client remains perfectly connected. I know about the `set_validate_handler` and I have already set up to allow only two connections at the same time, but with this the server remains listening. What I need is a way to make the server stop listening on the port.

I am trying to close the listening and remain with the already made connections this way:

```
void on_open( connection_hdl hdl )
{
    // Insert
    m_connections.insert( hdl );

    // Stop listening
    m_server.stop_listening();
}
```

However, it gives me the following output:

```
[2015-07-12 17:06:47] [connect] WebSocket Connection [::1]:58589 v13 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.132 Safari/537.36" / 101
[2015-07-12 17:06:47] [fail] WebSocket Connection Unknown - "" - 0 websocketpp:26 Operation canceled[2015-07-12 17:06:47] [info] Error getting remote endpoint: system:10009 (The file handle supplied is not valid)
[2015-07-12 17:06:47] [info] asio async_shutdown error: system:10009 (The file handle supplied is not valid)
remote_endpoint: The file handle supplied is not valid
```

The client is unable to even connect. If, otherwise, I use the `m_server.stop_listening();` after the establishment of the connection, the Client remains perfectly connected, but the server stops receiving its messages or at least I cannot get them on the `void on_message( connection_hdl hdl, server::message_ptr msg )`.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend re-thinking the design of the chat app (maybe it's better to have chatrooms with two participants each rather than a whole app for two connections?), I think you can write an easy 'dirty' solution...

...Why not have a "global" counter and simply refuse connections if the number is too high?

If to borrow from your code, maybe it will look something like this (I have no idea if this works, this is just an outline):

```
int connections_count = 0
void on_open( connection_hdl hdl )
{
    connections_count += 1
    if(connections_count >= 2) { return connection_hdl.close}
    // Insert
    m_connections.insert( hdl );
}
void on_close ( connection_hdl hdl )
{
    connections_count -= 1
}
```

Because my C++ coding sucks, I'll write a quick server example in Ruby using the [Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi)... Think of it as pseudo-code which you can run in `irb` (Ruby's terminal interpreter):

```
require 'plezi'

class ChatCtrl
   def pre_connect
      return self.class.add_client
   end

   def on_message data
     broadcast :_post_data, data
   end

   def on_disconnect
      self.class.remove_client
   end

   def _post_data data
     response << data
   end

   # these are class methods, designated by adding `self.` to the name
   # they hold the global number of connected clients.
   # they also handle the multi-threading security, because Plezi is multi-threaded.

   def self.add_client
      @locker ||= Mutex.new # multi-thread security
      @clients ||= 0
      return false if @clients >= 2
      @locker.synchronize { @clients += 1 }
   end
   def self.remove_client
      @locker.synchronize { @clients -= 1 }
   end
end

listen

route '*', ChatCtrl

exit
```

I added some multi-thread security, although it's probably not required if your app is single threaded.

This is ugly, but it should work.

Goodluck!